# nodejs read directory recursively, get files paths, then use paths to copy files to another directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

i use [recursive-readdir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-readdir) to read a directory and its subdirectories like this:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const recursive = require('recursive-readdir');

const inputFolder = './input';

const files =  await recursive(inputFolder)
```

then i filter the fetched files like this:

```
const fileteredFiles = files.filter((f) => f.includes('.gif'));
```

i console.log(filteredFiles) and this is the output:

```
[ 'input/background/black.gif',
  'input/background/grey.gif',]
```

now i want to copy black.gif and grey.gif to another directory, i tried this:

```
fse.copyFileSync(fileteredFiles, 'outputDir')
```

i get this error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "src" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object
    at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1719:3)
```

so please point me to the right way of grabbing filteredFiles and copying then to another directory.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In nodejs v16, you could use [`fsPromises.cp()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisescpsrc-dest-options) to copy a file hierarchy to a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `fs.copyFileSync` correctly in two separate ways:

1. The first argument to `fs.copyFileSync()` must be the source file path.  You are trying to pass an array of file paths.  That is not how it works.  You must call `fs.copyFileSync()` for ONE individual file.
2. The second argument to `fs.copyFileSync()` must be the destination file path, NOT a directory path.

Note that even if you try to use the `fs-extra` version named `fs.copySync()`, it says this:

> if src is a file, dest cannot be a directory

So, to fix your use of `fs.copyFileSync()`, you must call it for each file you want to copy and you must build the appropriate target file path (and not pass just the destination directory).

Note: Added to node v16 is an experimental interface for copying multiple files from one location to another with either [`fs.cpSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscpsyncsrc-dest-options), [`fs.cp()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fscpsrc-dest-options-callback) or [`fs.promises.cp()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisescpsrc-dest-options).  You could also try out that new interface as it will do a recursive copy for you and it offers a filter function so you could restrict it to just GIF files if you want.

Comment: @Nicholas Carey's provided a solution, and your answer helped in applying this solution with the right syntax..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the error message?

> ```
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "src" argument must be one of
> type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object
> ```

```
at Object.copyFileSync (fs.js:1719:3)
```

> 

You are passing a list/array of string to `fse.fileCopySync()`, rather than a single string. Try something like:

```js
for (const fn of filterFiles) {
  fse.copyFileSync( fn , 'outputdir' ); 
}
```

Comment: i used a for loop to solve this problem as the incrementor helps in naming files with i++, for example, file-1, file-2 and so on...thanks again